# Joomla 1.5 editing head information

Tags: html, joomla1.5, head

I was recently brought in to fix up a website that was originally published using Joomla v1.5. There are a few problems regarding the structure of the main page.

I would like to update the doctype to the newer html5 standard from xhtml transitional. Also, on every page of the site, there is a < link > tag that appears before the < head > tag. Does anyone know how I can make these edits?

When I go to edit the template html code, all I see is the following:

```
<?php

// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
include_once (dirname(__FILE__).DS.'libs'.DS.'ja.template.helper.php');


if( defined('_DEMO_MODE_') ) {
    $tmplTools = JATemplateHelper::getInstance($this, array('ui', JA_TOOL_SCREEN, JA_TOOL_MENU, JA_TOOL_COLOR, 'main_layout', 'direction'));
} else {
    $tmplTools = JATemplateHelper::getInstance($this, array('ui', JA_TOOL_SCREEN, JA_TOOL_MENU, 'main_layout', 'direction'));
}
//Calculate the width of template
$tmplWidth = '';
$tmplWrapMin = '100%';
switch ($tmplTools->getParam(JA_TOOL_SCREEN)){
    case 'auto':
        $tmplWidth = '97%';
        break;
    case 'fluid':
        $tmplWidth = intval($tmplTools->getParam('ja_screen-fluid-fix-ja_screen_width'));
        $tmplWidth = $tmplWidth ? $tmplWidth.'%' : '90%';
        break;
    case 'fix':
        $tmplWidth = intval($tmplTools->getParam('ja_screen-fluid-fix-ja_screen_width'));
        $tmplWrapMin = $tmplWidth ? ($tmplWidth+1).'px' : '771px';
        $tmplWidth = $tmplWidth ? $tmplWidth.'px' : '770px';
        break;
    default:
        $tmplWidth = intval($tmplTools->getParam(JA_TOOL_SCREEN));
        $tmplWrapMin = $tmplWidth ? ($tmplWidth+1).'px' : '981px';
        $tmplWidth = $tmplWidth ? $tmplWidth.'px' : '980px';
        break;
}

$tmplTools->setParam ('tmplWidth', $tmplWidth);
$tmplTools->setParam ('tmplWrapMin', $tmplWrapMin);

//Main navigation
$ja_menutype = $tmplTools->getParam(JA_TOOL_MENU, 'css');
$jamenu = null;
if ($ja_menutype && $ja_menutype != 'none') {
    $japarams = new JParameter('');
    $japarams->set( 'menutype', $tmplTools->getParam('menutype', 'mainmenu') );
    $japarams->set( 'menu_images_align', 'left' );
    $japarams->set( 'menupath', $tmplTools->templateurl() .'/ja_menus');
    $japarams->set('menu_images', 1); //0: not show image, 1: show image which set in menu item
    $japarams->set('menu_background', 1); //0: image, 1: background
    $japarams->set('mega-colwidth', 200); //Megamenu only: Default column width
    $jamenu = $tmplTools->loadMenu($japarams, $ja_menutype); 
}   
//End for main navigation

$layout = $tmplTools->getLayout ();
if ($layout) {
    $tmplTools->display ($layout);
}
```

[image: templates view]

[image: code part 1]

[image: code part 2]

Comment: do you have ftp access or are you asking for a method to do this from within Joomla?

Comment: I just updated this question a bit, but I would prefer to do this within Joomla if at all possible. Currently I do not have the FTP login info.

Comment: Can you also insert: a screenshot of your templates and the screen where you see this code. Are you sure this is the correct template?Something seems to be missing here.

Comment: Im not sure what is missing but it does seem like something is. I added the images above, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the template with Tools->Template Manager->check template->Edit->Edit HTML or Edit CSS.

It can be quite scary to do this through an HTML editor, but its available.

To my knowledge you need Super Admin rights for this

Comment: When I go in to edit the HTML, all I see is a fat block of php code. Can I find the html head code through here? Its strange because I do see the HTML in the other, inactive templates. Any idea why that may be? If you need any info from the code let me know.

Comment: Its quite common for a template to have a lot of PHP at the beginning. Can you search for <head and then see what comes up?

Comment: < head > doesn't appear at all. The only code listed is php, there isn't any Html at all.

Comment: can you paste it here

Comment: At the top of your file there's an `include` that refers to `ja.template.helper.php`. Have you looked in that file?

Comment: I posted the code on to the original question, @jdog … And I have been unsuccessful in locating that file through Joomla. Any idea where it might be?

Comment: I recently got FTP access set up. I have checked the ja.template.helper.php file that is included but there is still no html code present. Does anyone know where I could make the edits above now that ftp is a possibility?